# Abrir um ficheiro PowerBI em C#

Tags: c#, powerbi

Estou a fazer um programa em c# que visa procurar ficheiros `.pbix` e depois mostrá-los num painel dentro da aplicação...
O que acontece é o seguinte eu procuro o ficheiro, abro-o e ele vai abrir o ficheiro fora da aplicação não mostrando nada dentro do painel...
O código é:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Te_connectivity
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 newForm1 = new Form1();
            this.Hide(); // use dessa maneira.
            newForm1.ShowDialog();
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Process proc = Process.Start(od.FileName);
                proc.WaitForInputIdle();

                while(proc.MainWindowHandle== IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    proc.Refresh();
                }
                SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panel1.Handle);
            }
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer integrar um relatório do Power BI em seu aplicativo C#?

Comment: Sim pode ser umas das soluções.

Comment: Se você quer abrir um arquivo do Power Bi para acessar suas tabelas pode dar uma olhada neste link https://dataonwheels.wordpress.com/2021/10/15/power-bi-meets-programmability-tom-xmla-and-c/
Se você quer incorporar um relatório em sua aplicação pode dar uma olhada na API do PowerBI